# Bootstrap v4.6.0. dropdown-toggle съезжает под ссылку пункта меню. Почему?

Tags: bootstrap4

В одном из пунктов навбара необходимо выводить подменю. Добавляю в class="nav-link **dropdown-toggle**"

В результате получаю

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как выводить dropdown-toggle справа от пункта меню? Вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
                      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><h5>Подменю</h5></a>
                      <div class="dropdown-menu border-0" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><h5>Пункт 1</h5></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><h5>Пункт 2</h5></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><h5>Пункт 3</h5></a>
                      </div>
                    </li>
```

Comment: попробуйте увеличить ширину элемента, либо же посмотреть какие стили влияют на элемент в инструментах разработчика в браузере

Comment: @highpassion Менял отступы конкретно у nav-item и у nav-item, устанавливал ширину и auto и >100%. Ничего не помогает. Пробежался по стилям элементов, не нашел, что влияет на положение тоглера.

Comment: если у элемента нет max-width, то попробуйте изменить размеры вложенного элемента `a`, а лучше попробуйте предоставить код в песочнице, чтобы наглядно можно понять, влияют ли какие-то унаследованные стили на элемент.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте изменить ширину элемента или прописать `white-space: nowrap`

Comment: nowrap уже есть в стилях Bootstrap 4 [Скриншот](https://i.ibb.co/jgX4g9X/23-07-2021-102131.jpg)